# O.K. oder OK oder o.k. oder ok

Tags: abbreviation

Könnten Sie mir bitte sagen, welche Abkürzung korrekt ist? Ich versuchte, die Informationen am Forum zu finden, aber leider fand ich keine.

1. O.K.
2. OK
3. o.k.
4. ok

Answer (score 4):

Alle vier Abkürzungen sind okay, eine weitere Schreibung ist *okay*.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/okay

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/okay